# Bluemix using Node-RED bind to existing ClearDB MySQL service

Tags: mysql, node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red, cleardb

I am using Node-RED on IBM Bluemix. I am trying to connect to MySQL hosted by ClearDB, but I cannot find a suitable node in the database category.

How can I bind to existing ClearDB service that I already have bound to another app?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [MySQL node for Node-RED](http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-mysql) in the flow and node library, it is an extension. The steps to add additional node types to the editor is explained in the [Node-RED documentation](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/adding-nodes) in general, however it does not directly apply to Bluemix. For your Bluemix environment you would need to access and modify the environment. See this [post on how to deploy your customized Node-RED environment to Bluemix](http://heidloff.net/article/customization-node-red-bluemix).